# How to delete files from local machine using ftp command?

Tags: batch-file, ftp, batch-processing, ftp-client

I am using the following ftp commands to transfer files from my local mashine to the remote mashine. After that I want to delete the files from the local mashine. Which command I should use for my case? The command must be inserted after mput *.*

```
open xx.xxx.xxx.xx
username
password
cd \path\to\remote\mashine
lcd \path\to\local\mashine
binary
mput *.*
disconnect
bye
```

Comment: Have you tryied "delete x.x"? With asterisks in the place of the "x" from my expression (Stackoverflow doesn't permit asterisks here). Delete is the ftp command for file deletion.

Answer (score 2):

1. Move the local files to a temporary location before starting the FTP session

   `move *.* TEMPDIR`
2. Upload them

   `mput TEMPDIR\*.*`
3. Delete them when the FTP session ends

   `del /q TEMPDIR\*.*`

Comment: Maybe you did not understand the answer. You need to create a batch file (.bat) with lines like: `move *.* TEMPDIR`  -  `ftp -s:ftp.txt`  - `del /q TEMPDIR\*.*`